# Controller Method not working

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm having a problem hitting a controller method with a browser(Chrome or IE).  In the controller there are 2 methods index and RedirectToDownTown(MyModel model).  I want the url for the RedirectToDownTown method to be https://[myserver]/RedirectToDownTown instead of https://[myserver]/Home/RedirectToDownTown.  When I hit the https://[myserver]/RedirectToDownTown URL with a browser, I get the error message below.

When I hit the https://[myserver]/Home/RedirectToDownTown I don't get the error message.  I found on stack overflow another post with the same error saying that it's because the controller is an API controller and doesn't inherit from IController.  However, mine inherits from Controller which inherits from IController.

What can I do to have the URL for this method be https://[myserver]/RedirectToDownTown ?

Thanks

Jim

Answer (score 1):

Add to RouteConfig.cs

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "RedirectToDownTownName",
        url: "RedirectToDownTown",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDownTown" });
```

Comment: Where did you add this code? It should be **before** _Default_ route